# Split CSV into multiple files based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a poorly-structured CSV file named `file.csv`, and I want to split it up into multiple CSV using Python.

```
|A|B|C|
|Continent||1|
|Family|44950|file1|
|Species|44950|12|
|Habitat||4|
|Species|44950|22|
|Condition|Tue Jan 24 00:00:00 UTC 2023|4|
|Family|Fish|file2|
|Species|Bass|8|
|Species|Trout|2|
|Habitat|River|3|
```

The new files need to be separated based on everything between the `Family` rows, so for example:

`file1.csv`

```
|A|B|C|
|Continent||1|
|Family|44950|file1|
|Species|44950|12|
|Habitat||4|
|Species|44950|22|
|Condition|Tue Jan 24 00:00:00 UTC 2023|4|
```

`file2.csv`

```
|A|B|C|
|Continent||1|
|Family|Fish|file2|
|Species|Bass|8|
|Species|Trout|2|
|Habitat|River|3|
```

What's the best way of achieving this when the number of rows between appearances of `Species` is not consistent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file really looks like that ;) then you could use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) from the standard library module `itertools`:

```py
from itertools import groupby

def key(line): return line.startswith("|Family|")

family_line, file_no = None, 0
with open("file.csv", "r") as fin:
    for is_family_line, lines in groupby(fin, key=key):
        if is_family_line:
            family_line = list(lines).pop()
        elif family_line is None:
            header = "".join(lines)
        else:
            file_no += 1
            with open(f"file{file_no}.csv", "w") as fout:
                fout.write(header + family_line)
                for line in lines:
                    fout.write(line)
```

A Pandas solution would be:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv", header=None, delimiter="|").fillna("")
blocks = df.iloc[:, 1].eq("Family").cumsum()
header_df = df[blocks.eq(0)]
for no, sdf in df.groupby(blocks):
    if no > 0:
        sdf = pd.concat([header_df, sdf])
        sdf.to_csv(f"file{no}.csv", index=False, header=False, sep="|")
```

Comment: Thanks, the pandas solution works well. What if I wanted to keep the header columns persistent throughout each file though?

Comment: @MSD Thanks for the feedback. I've adjusted both solutions to take that into account (seems to work here). In the Pandas version you could use `df["A"]` instead of `df.iloc[:, 1]` - but it seemed to me that `A` might not be the real column label, so I made it a bit more generic.

Comment: @MSD Ah, sorry, I've just realized that you want the first 2 rows as header, not just the first - is that correct?

Comment: Yeah that's correct. Sorry I don't think I called that out in my original post (and yes, it's a very gnarly CSV).

Comment: @MSD Okay, thanks: I've updated both versions and think they work.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('file.csv',delimiter='|')
groups = df.groupby('Family')
for name, group in groups:
    group.to_csv(name + '.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: That doesn't work: `df` has no column `Family`, and even if it had one the results would be completely different from what the question asks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure python working method:

```
# Read file
with open('file.csv', 'r') as file:
    text = file.read()

# Split using |Family|
splitted_text = text.split("|Family|")

# Remove unwanted content before first |Family|
splitted_text = splitted_text[1:]

# Add |Family| back to each part
splitted_text = ['|Family|' + item for item in splitted_text]

# Write files
for i, content in enumerate(splitted_text ):
    with open('file{}.csv'.format(i), 'w') as file:
        file.write(content)
```